# Using sort | awk on one column from a csv?

Tags: sorting, awk, cat

Using p.txt:

```
$cat p.txt
R 3
R 4
S 1
S 2
R 1
T 1
R 3
```

The following command sorts based on the second column:

```
$cat p.txt | sort -k2
R 1
S 1
T 1
S 2
R 3
R 3
R 4
```

The following command removes repeated values in the second column:

```
$cat p.txt | sort -k2 | awk '!x[$2]++'
R 1
S 2
R 3
R 4
```

Now inserting a comma for the sapce, we have the following file:

```
$cat p1.csv
R,3
R,4
S,1
S,2
R,1
T,1
R,3
```

The following command still sorts based on the second column:

```
$cat p1.csv | sort -t "," -k2
R,1
S,1
T,1
S,2
R,3
R,3
R,4
```

Below is NOT the correct output:

```
$cat p1.csv | sort -t "," -k2 | awk '!x[$2]++'
R,1
```

Correct output:

```
R,1
S,2
R,3
R,4
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `awk -F,` in your last command. So:

```
cat p1.csv | sort -t "," -k2 | awk -F, '!x[$2]++'
```

Since your fields are separated by commas, you need to tell awk that the field separator is no longer whitespace, but instead the comma. The `-F` option to awk does that.

Comment: good to point out the problem however cat and awk are not needed on this problem

Answer (score 5):

well you have already used sort, then you don't need the awk at all. sort has `-u`

Also the `cat` is not needed either:

```
sort -t, -k2 -u p1.csv
```

should give you expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Well you don't need all such things, `sort` and `uniq` are enough to do such things

```
sort -t "," -k2 p1.csv | uniq -s 2
```

`uniq -s 2` tells uniq to skip first 2 characters (i.e. till `,`)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been trying to figure out how to get a count of the repeated values in column two.  Your post made it possibile:    cat p1.csv | sort -t "," -k2 | uniq -s2 -c

Comment: @absu: is there some way to use uniq with fields rather than characters?  If the character length varies in the first column, then the # in uniq -s# needs to vary.

Comment: Actually, i see that `uniq -f` gives you a flexibility to mention number of fields to be skipped, but I don't see any option to mention `,` as a field separator, perhaps `IFS` would need to be changed or `sort -t "," -k2 p1.csv | tr ',' ' '|uniq -f 1 |tr ' ' ','` But I think as Kent pointed out, `sort` already has a `-u`, so that also should be noted :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide field separator for `awk`

```
 cat p1.csv | sort -t "," -k2 | awk -F, '!x[$2]++'
```